# Best practice for multi level menu in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a good solution to keep track of menu items that was open when visiting down level menus. Like this:

```
- Person
    - Config
        - Local
        - Address
- Pages
```

When clicking "Local", I need to know that "Person" and "Config" are open, to render then correctly.

---

Currently I´m using a session variable to store the parent menus. I set this variable in the index action of a controller. So, in "AddressController" I set it to something like ["Person", "Config"].

Comment: Have you had a look at [MvcSiteMapProvider?](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider)

Comment: Yes I did, but it´s not what I need.  I need to keep all parent menus opened when visiting a inner page.

Comment: Are you looking for best practice or a solution? In context of best practice you should mention what approach you have used so far.